# Point to an array within a 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

EDIT2: I tried to approximate my actual code here, but apparently I missed something, since this code isn't generating the warnings I'm getting in my actual code. I'm closing this until I can figure out the discrepancy.

## Original Question

What is the syntax for pointing to an array (row) within a 2D array such as shown below? How then would I access individual elements within it using the row pointer?

```
int arr[3][4] =
{
    {0, 1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6, 7},
    {8, 9, 10, 11},
};
```

EDIT:

If I do

```
int const * pRow = arr[1];
```

I get the compiler warning

```
warning C4047: '=': 'const int *' differs in levels of indirection from 'const int (*)[4]'
```

Is there a "right" way to do this, besides just forcing it with casts?

Comment: what is the issue with `arr[n]`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh, what is the type for the variable which would point to `arr[n]`?

Comment: What do you mean point to? it is the same as `arr[m]`, in case the array was defined as `arr[n][m]`

Comment: Your error message does not appear to be consistent with the code you've presented.  In particular, if the message is indeed attributable to the line you present then it suggests that `arr` is declared as a *three*-dimensional array with `const` ultimate elements.

Comment: [I can't replicate your error](http://rextester.com/TGA79973). This is why you need to try and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In fact, `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` accepts the declarations you've given for `arr` and `pRow` with nary a peep.  I dunno how to elicit more diagnostics from `gcc` than that will do.

Comment: That warning only makes sense if you wrote `int const * pRow = arr;` or `int const * pRow = &arr[1];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arr[m]` is an array of `int`, and as all arrays it naturally decays to a pointer to its first element. Now what is the type of the first element of `arr[m]` (i.e. `arr[m][0]`)? It's an `int` right? So `arr[m]` decays to a pointer to `int`, i.e. `int*`.

That means you can do something like

```
int *ptr_to_arr_1 = arr[1];
```

You can use `ptr_to_arr_1` as any other array or pointer. So to access the second element you have `ptr_to_arr_1[1]`, and it's the same as `arr[1][1]`.

Comment: Please see my revised question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `int * ptr_to_row=arr[row_no];`

Comment: try it without const

Comment: removing the const adds a new warning, `warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers`. Plus I should be able to have a pointer to const data, even if the data isn't const, it just means I can't modify it through the pointer.

Comment: http://computer-programming-forum.com/17-c-language/c3aae7b73f1bd869.htm  read here about this